# Is it possible to assign a ringtone to a group of contacts?

Tags: iphone, contacts, ringtones

Without individually setting the ringtone for each contact in that group.

Maybe there are other apps that manage contacts and have this feature.

Basically, I want my iPhone to ring the same when contacts from a group call.

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature that I want Apple to support, but hasn't yet. The "Group" mechanism in Contacts is a distribution list and only allows you to group contacts but has no editable meta information for you to change (for example, to change the default ringtone).

On an un-hacked iPhone, your only option is to edit individual contacts, and assign the new ringtone for each of them.

I have never hacked my iPhone, so there might be alternative methods available that I am not aware of. I will let someone else with a hacked iPhone answer that part.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Agreed with above